# How to make iOS app orientation portrait only?

Tags: ios, swift

How do I make my iOS app Portrait Only? It looks like it's already in portrait mode currently but when I flip my device it rotates still. I am using tableViews and collectionViews within my app, I'm not sure if they would affect these settings or not.

[image: deployment info]

Comment: You can't really tell anything from that interface. Please show the relevant parts of the Info.plist.

Comment: @matt I had to add "Supported interface orientations (iPhone)" and set it to portrait in my info.plist and now it's working. Thank you for pointing out where to look!

Comment: You bet. The interface you showed does work but it's really really confusing. Doing this directly in the Info.plist is a lot clearer. 

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem I had to add "Supported interface orientations (iPhone)" and set the item to "Portrait (bottom home button)" in my info.plist file

[image]